# Scrollview will not scroll

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is part of an app where the user checks various checkboxes for things they are looking for in trees, and then a list of fitting trees is displayed.

I have an activity with an edittext field and button at the top of the screen, and then below them both is a scrollview that has a single textview within it (obviously inside a linear layout). Based on various checkboxes that the user checks in a previous activity, the size of the textview varies.

The problem is when the textview becomes a very long list: I cannot scroll down the screen to view the entire list. I can only see what is at the top part of the list.

Here is my xml for the activity:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Item..."
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:text="Find"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="301dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="301dp"
    android:onClick="find" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout">

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="Results..."
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why wont the scrolling work?

Comment: ScrollView seems empty?

Comment: Move </ScrollView> below </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Item..."
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:text="Find"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="301dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="301dp"
    android:onClick="find" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="Results..."
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```